# Java: I compare two Strings but it didn't recognize it

Tags: java, arrays, string, compare

I have this problem:

I wrote this function because I need to get the index of the occurrence of a particular string `st` in a String array

```
static public int indicestring(String[] array, String st) {
    int ret = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (st.equals(array[i])) {
            ret=i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I then called:

```
System.out.println("indicestring(NODO,"ET2"));
```

and I got the correct number.

But then when I do:

```
String[] arcos2 = linea.split("-");//reading from a file and separating by "-"
String aux = arcos2[1];

System.out.println(arcos2[1]);
System.out.println(aux);

if (aux.equals(arcos2[1])) {
    System.out.println("Is equal 1");
}

if (aux.equals("ET2")) {
    System.out.println("Is equal 2");
}

if ("ET2".equals(aux)) {
    System.out.println("is equal 3");
}
```

The first two prints were `ET2`, but then it only printed  of the 3 ifs is "Is equal 1".... The thing is I have nearly 200 nodes like "ET2" and only 3 are failing and giving me -1 in the first function...

My question is....Am I using wrong the arrays to save and compare the data, because if aux=arcos2[1]="ET2", why  is 'aux.equals("ET2") 'or 'arcos2[1].equals("ET2)' not working
? Is ther another function you can recommend to try?(I tried changing equals with `compareTo() == 0` and that didn't work either and trimming was also recommended).

Before, I had a similar error where I compare  two arrays like this:

```
if(a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1])
```

There was a case that clearly was correct but  it was ignored...
But it got corrected when a i changed it to:

```
if (Arrays.equals(a, b))
```

Is there maybe some change like that

Comment: Can you clarify your post more; I'm not sure on what you're asking now

Comment: Try trimming the strings before comparing them, may be there is some leading or trailing space coming,Do it like, if(aux.equals(arcos2[1].trim()))

Comment: trimming didn't work u.u ...thanks

Comment: Michael , i tried to clarify my doubt...tell me if it's enough

Comment: Print out the length of `aux`, and ideally each character within it, separately as an `int` so you can see the UTF-16 code units involved.

Comment: Provide some sample data from the file you reading for better understanding of the problem

Comment: wait!!! now i noticed  with  trim()    works  :D  ...thanks everyone and ValarMorghulis ;D

Answer (score 1):

You should put a debug break point in the code and add expression watches to identify the root cause of the problem.